# How to know the procedure by which subroutine called? in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine

I sometimes has error on subroutine.The subroutine is called by many procedure. So, I try to find caller procedure for step over.

By the way, *user-defined function* can know the caller.
It is simply.

```
MsgBox Application.Caller
```

We can see dialog and caller cell address.

I want to know caller procedure of subroutine.

Comment: Do you want to use a code to find what you require? If not then @Santosh's reply is what you want. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Old question, I know, but I am trying to do this with code. Any ideas?

Comment: I still don't know to access call stack in vba code.
Better idea, (not best) is sending parent submodule name to called submodule on each caller submodule.

Or, create original call stack ( https://hammondmason.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/creating-a-call-stack-in-vba/ ). 
But this idea is also scattering stack code, it's not that bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Call Stack Dialog Box**

For example in the below image proc3 was called by proc2 which is displayed in call stack dialog box.

[image]

Comment: + 1 For Non VBA method. Good One :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  feel gud to get +1 from you sirjee

Comment: Naoya Yamashita kindly zoom the image or may be see it on a bigger screen.

Comment: Sorry, browser renew makes it batter.

Comment: Finaly, We cannot know caller procedure name on code?

I want to use in message box.

Comment: @NaoyaYamashita If you are calling proc2 from proc1 you can pass the name of proc1 as a string parameter to proc2. This will help you to display a message in proc2.