# Is there a way to tell if the Sub currently running is the parent or a called child

Tags: excel, vba

I have routines in VBA that can run standalone or can be called by another routine. When called as a subroutine (child) or as a primary routine (parent) there are operations that I may or may not want to execute. Is there a built-in function in VBA that I can call that will tell me if my executing code is a parent or child?

I have created global variables to test for parent/child but I would like to have a more elegant solution.

Comment: You said you have used global variables, why would that not be elegant? Just use a public boolean variable that gets set to `True` in the case a subroutine is called within another routine.

Comment: I guess in my mind, an elegant solution would be a one-step solution vs a multi-step solution. Using global variables is a three step solution - declare variable. set variable, test variable. I'm look for a one-step solution like "if cursub>0 then.." if cursub is the child (1), grandchild (2), etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696462/how-to-know-the-procedure-by-which-subroutine-called-in-excel-vba

Comment: And also see [THIS](https://hammondmason.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/creating-a-call-stack-in-vba/) link mentioned in the above link as well.

Comment: non-VBA solution: hit [**CTRL+L**] in the code editor to view to call stack.

Answer (score 3):

I think a good way would be to have a procedure for the action itself that has a switch (parameter) and a procedure that calls it.

```
Private Sub MyProcedure(Optional ByVal IsChild As Boolean = True) 'set default here
    If IsChild Then
        'child
    Else
        'parent
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can have a procedure to call it

```
Public Sub ParentCallMyProcedure()
    MyProcedure IsChild:=False
End Sub

Public Sub ChildCallMyProcedure()
    MyProcedure IsChild:=True
    'which would be the same as
    MyProcedure
End Sub
```

Eg if you want to call `MyProcedure` from a button then use

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    MyProcedure IsChild:=False
End Sub
```

In all other procedures just use `MyProcedure` and `IsChild` is default `True`.

At least this is more elegant than a public/global variable.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net getting info for a method, which called a method is called [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). It is quite straight-forward in C# - [How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method). VBA does not support it, but you could run around it, and log somewhere data about it - through a variable or logging to a worksheet or database.

There is a way to do it, if you stop the code in the middle of the called sub/function and call the [Call Stack diaglog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-stack-dialog-box). E.g., imagine the following seqeuence:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Testme2
End Sub

Sub Testme2()
    Stop
End Sub
```

If you run the code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> once you are on the `Stop` you would get this:

[image]

If you only run `TestMe2` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, you would get it correspondingly:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could do this, which is great, but I'm hoping to have something that I can run in the code to tell me if I'm currently a parent or a child. If you're familiar with SAP, you can use the "session.Children.count" function to perform similar.

Comment: @JoeMessingschlager - the only solution I can think about is usage of a variable or logging into an Excel sheet (which is pretty much the same).

Answer (score 1):

While the following is not really a solution it may work depending on your setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my Occam's Razor solution that I have used in the past.

```
Public ChildCount as Integer
Sub EveryProc()
  ChildCount = ChildCount + 1
  ... rest of code...
  ChildCount = ChildCount - 1
  End Sub
```

This allows me to test how far I am into subroutines as ChildCount will  be 1 for the parent and >1 for the children. I think the first time into the VBA, ChildCount will be zero so you need to increment and decrement the variable at the beginning and end of every sub.
I am spoiled in SAP...